# how to directly connect the hosts with the controller in Mininet

Tags: mininet, sdn

is it possible to directly connect a host with the controller in Mininet?
Say, we have created a SDN network with Mininet and it contains host H1 and controller C1.
Now, I want to send msgs between C1 and H1. How can I do it?

Also, the communication "link" between C1 and H1 is not necessary to belong to the SDN network. The link can belong to a separate network.

Many thanks!

Comment: You want a in-band controller ? Perhaps read this http://pox-dev.noxrepo.narkive.com/8KtfIMxN/can-pox-connect-or-communicate-with-host

Comment: @SotirisTsartsaris the weblink not available. Would you put the content in new answer?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever the host (*H1* in this case) sends a message which matches no OpenFlow rules in the switch, it will automatically be send to the controller, as the switch does not know what to do with it. This is the default behavior of OpenFlow/Mininet.

Comment: Thanks for information. Where could see default setting in Mininet?